# Write a non-recursive traversal of a Binary Search Tree using constant space and O(n) run time

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal, tree-traversal

**This is not homework, this is an interview question.**

The catch here is that the algorithm should be constant space.
I'm pretty clueless on how to do this without a stack, I'd post what I've written using a stack, but it's not relevant anyway.

Here's what I've tried: I attempted to do a pre-order traversal and I got to the left-most node, but I'm stuck there. I don't know how to "recurse" back up without a stack/parent pointer.

Any help would be appreciated.

(I'm tagging it as Java since that's what I'm comfortable using, but it's pretty language agnostic as is apparent.)

Comment: I don't see a way of doing this without a stack or parent pointer either.

Comment: Mh, does each node have a reference to it's parent?

Comment: @ChrisWue - nope, that would have been straight-forward :)

Comment: are you sure he asked for a pre-order traversal and not just any other traversal?

Comment: Any traversal would work, I just began with a pre-order traversal because that's what I know best.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I didn't think it through entirely, but i think it's possible as long as you're willing to mess up your tree in the process.

Every Node has 2 pointers, so it could be used to represent a doubly-linked list. Suppose you advance from Root to Root.Left=Current. Now Root.Left pointer is useless, so assign it to be Current.Right and proceed to Current.Left. By the time you reach leftmost child, you'll have a linked list with trees hanging off of some nodes. Now iterate over that, repeating the process for every tree you encounter as you go

EDIT: thought it through. Here's the algorithm that prints in-order:

```
void traverse (Node root) {
  traverse (root.left, root);
}

void traverse (Node current, Node parent) {
  while (current != null) {
    if (parent != null) {
      parent.left = current.right;
      current.right = parent;
    }

    if (current.left != null) {
      parent = current;
      current = current.left;
    } else {
      print(current);
      current = current.right;
      parent = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, that is a good idea. It's called pointer reversal and sometimes used by garbage collectors. It has relation to Huet's zipper. But as you said, it messes up your tree and often violates static type safety.

Comment: (+1) for the idea, but please explain why you think this has `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: Because every node gets visited exactly once (one iteration, one node), and there's a constant amount of operations in an iteration

Comment: What happens if the root just has a right subtree .. it will never enter the while loop and the tree would not be traversed ! ... while(current != null|| parent!= null) should fix it imo ..

Comment: When one just needs to traverse the tree from the root to a given node, and back again (like when inserting a node in an AVL tree and performing rotations on the way back to the root), one can still use this pointer reversal technique. Go down left (resp. right) branch: `next = current.left /*resp. right*/; current.left /*resp. right*/ = parent; parent = current; current = next;`. When going up: `if (current.value < parent.value) { grandparent = parent.left; parent.left = current; } else { grandparent = parent.right; parent.right = current; } current = parent; parent = grandparent;`.

Answer (score 30):

How about Morris Inorder tree traversal? Its based on the notion of threaded trees and it modifies the tree, but reverts it back when its done.

Linkie: http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=6358

Doesn't use any extra space.

Comment: Thank you - so **this** was what was being asked for. Thanks again!

Comment: If it helps you any bit, I asked a question about how the tree is restored here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502916/please-explain-morris-inorder-tree-traversal-without-using-stacks-or-recursion

Comment: @user183037 Interesting concept, but this does not use a Binary Search Tree, so it isn't quite inline with the OP's question. Binary Search Tree being left values are always less than and right values are always greater than the value of the parent node.

Comment: @brainydexter Good link but the Morris traversal explained runs in O(nlogn) time complexity and not O(n) time as asked.

Comment: with just a link, this'll become useless when the link dies

Comment: @NikunjBanka The Morris traversal is O(n) not O(nlogn). The linked article explains why. But basically, when we are looking for preorder node (by going down the right child nodes of the left child) those nodes are visited for this purpose only once. And then of course once more when they are processed themselves.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a downwards pointer based tree and don't have a parent pointer or some other memory it is impossible to traverse in constant space.

It is possible if your binary tree is in an array instead of a pointer-based object structure. But then you can access any node directly. Which is a kind of cheating ;-)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call that cheating, but you're forgetting that the algorithm needs to run on constant space - introducing an array is going to take O(N) space :)

Comment: @user183037: No, I meant if the tree is genuinely stored in an array instead of a pointer based structure. Such a representation is unusual but sometimes very efficient and useful. I'll edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: I think jmg means that the original tree you want to traverse is already stored in an array.

Comment: @ChrisWue: Exactly, that is what I meant.

Comment: and @ChrisWue - sorry, my bad. But I doubt that it would have been an array implementation. Good catch though!

Comment: "If you are using a downwards pointer based tree and don't have a parent pointer or some other memory it is impossible to traverse in constant space." - This isn't true if you are allowed to modify the tree during traversal (and then undo the changes). See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/

Comment: @mdenton8: You are absolutely right, then you could do the usual pointer reversal, aka zipper trick.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter version iluxa's [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5496559/3806468).
It runs exactly the same node manipulation and printing steps, in exactly the same order — but in a simplified manner [1]:

```
void traverse (Node n) {
  while (n) {
    Node next = n.left;
    if (next) {
      n.left = next.right;
      next.right = n;
      n = next;
    } else {
      print(n);
      n = n.right;
    }
  }
}
```

[1]
Plus, it even works when the tree root node has no left child.

Answer (score 0):

It's a a search tree, so you can always get the next key/entry

You need smth like  (I didn't test the code, but it's as simple as it gets)

```
java.util.NavigableMap<K, V> map=...
for (Entry<K, V> e = map.firstEntry(); e!=null; e = map.higherEntry(e.getKey())) {
  process(e)
}
```

for clarity this is `higherEntry`, so it's not recursive. There you have it :)

```
final Entry<K,V> getHigherEntry(K key) {
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    while (p != null) {
        int cmp = compare(key, p.key);
        if (cmp < 0) {
            if (p.left != null)
                p = p.left;
            else
                return p;
        } else {
            if (p.right != null) {
                p = p.right;
            } else {
                Entry<K,V> parent = p.parent;
                Entry<K,V> ch = p;
                while (parent != null && ch == parent.right) {
                    ch = parent;
                    parent = parent.parent;
                }
                return parent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you the line `Entry<K,V> parent = p.parent;`. This is the line where this code uses a parent pointer. Which is usually not present in a binary search tree. Otherwise, the interview question would be trivial.

Comment: And, this is not O(N) either AFAIK.

Comment: it's N*logN, but you can keep the pointer to the node to remove the logN.

Comment: @jmg, no one said there should be no parent. Red/Black is definitely a binary search tree.

Comment: @bestsss: Yes, but this implementation is more than just a binary search tree.

Comment: @bestsss - it's in the question description and in one of the comments on the question actually. Having a parent pointer makes the solution very straight-forward.

Comment: @jmg, it's an interview question and as far as I saw, there was no reference how to impl. the tree.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question doesn't mention the lack of a "parent" pointer in the node. Although it isn't necessarily required for BST, many binary tree implementations do have a parent pointer.
    class Node {
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        Node* parent;
        DATA data;
    };

It this is the case, imaging a diagram of the tree on paper, and draw with a pencil around the tree, going up and down, from both sides of the edges (when going down, you'll be left of the edge, and when going up, you'll be on the right side). Basically, there are 4 states:

1. SouthWest: You are on the left side of the edge, going from the parent its left child
2. NorthEast: Going from a left child, back to its parent
3. SouthEast: Going from a parent to a right child
4. NorthWest: Going from a right child, back to its parent

```
Traverse( Node* node )
{
    enum DIRECTION {SW, NE, SE, NW};
    DIRECTION direction=SW;

    while( node )
    {
        // first, output the node data, if I'm on my way down:
        if( direction==SE or direction==SW ) {
            out_stream << node->data;
        }

        switch( direction ) {
        case SW:                
            if( node->left ) {
                // if we have a left child, keep going down left
                node = node->left;
            }
            else if( node->right ) {
                // we don't have a left child, go right
                node = node->right;
                DIRECTION = SE;
            }
            else {
                // no children, go up.
                DIRECTION = NE;
            }
            break;
        case SE:
            if( node->left ) {
                DIRECTION = SW;
                node = node->left;
            }
            else if( node->right ) {
                node = node->right;
            }
            else {
                DIRECTION = NW;
            }
            break;
        case NE:
            if( node->right ) {
                // take a u-turn back to the right node
                node = node->right;
                DIRECTION = SE;
            }
            else {
                node = node->parent;
            }
            break;
        case NW:
            node = node->parent;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the question description, there's a point to a description field you know :p There is no parent pointer, if there was, the answer is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

We can traverse the binary tree without modifying the tree itself (provided nodes have parent pointer). And it can be done in constant space. I found this useful link for the same
http://tech.technoflirt.com/2011/03/04/non-recursive-tree-traversal-in-on-using-constant-space/

Comment: Sigh. there is *no* parent pointer. If there was one, it would have been a trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer needs the following change otherwise it will not print the tree where the BST only has one node

```
if (current == NULL && root != NULL)
   print(root);
```

Answer (score 0):

minor special case for iluxa's answer above

```
if(current== null)
        {
            current = root;
            parent = current.Right;
            if(parent != null)
            {
                current.Right = parent.Left;
                parent.Left = current;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a *binary* search tree, so every node can be reached by a series of right/left decision.  Describe that series as 0/1, least-significant bit to most-significant.  So the function f(0) means "the node found by taking the right-hand branch until you find a leaf; f(1) means take one left and the rest right; f(2) -- that is, binary 010 -- means take a right, then a left, then rights until you find a leaf.  Iterate f(n) starting at n=0 until you have hit every leaf.  Not efficient (since you have to start at the top of the tree each time) but constant memory and linear time.

Comment: You need `log(n)` bits to do this, so I doubt this qualifies as "constant space".

Comment: But then you have to store a series of bits (0/1 values) which can't be done in constant space unless you know an upper bound on the depth of the tree. But then even recursion uses only constant space.

Comment: this isn't linear time, it's nlogn if the tree is balanced and worse if it is not.

Comment: @jmg - are you sure? Recursion uses a stack internally, doesn't it?

Comment: @aix -- That's true.  If you had, for example, 18,446,744,073,709,551,616, you would need all of a 64-bit number to hold it.  I'm not worried.  (Yeah, a grossly imbalanced tree could defeat my algorithm, but it would defeat *any* constant-space algorithm, so I think it's fair to exclude it.)

Comment: @Bwmat -- it's n * m where m is the depth, but the depth is realistically limited (and yes, bounded by log(n)).  NB: I'm assuming everybody is using n to mean the number of nodes.

Comment: @user183037: Yes, I'm sure. And yes recursion uses a stack, but if the depth of the tree has an upper bound, the recursion depth has a proportional upper bound. Therefore, you can determine beforehand how much memory you will need. And that is usually called "constant space".

Comment: @user183037:  The concept of recursion has no inherent complexity. Depending on the context, a recursive function may be in any complexity class, e.g. O(1), O(log n), O(n), O(n^n) and so on.

Comment: @jmg - recursion is log(n) space. Anything that's in any way dependent on size of input (N) is f(N) and is not constant. If the tree isn't balanced, depth of recursion will equal N - how can you call that constant?

Comment: @iluxa: I said "the concept of recursion" and meant in general, not a recursive function to iterate through a pointer based binary search tree without parent pointers.

Comment: @jmg ok then. It's just that 2 comments ago you suggested that when "you can determine beforehand how much memory you will need, it's constant space", and that's incorrect.

Comment: it's constant space if you can determine beforehand an upper bound for the space needed, independent of n

Comment: @iluxa: Bwmat rephrased exactly what I said, I hope that make it clear to you.

Comment: @jmg and @Bwmat - so are you saying that, for example, to copy an array over to another array, you'll be using "constant space" since you already know how big the first array is?

Comment: @user183037: Yes, if for every possible input of the code under investigation the array size is constant. If you're interested in that, try to find an introduction into complexity theory.