# Runtime of Morris inorder tree traversal algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I just learned about the Morris inorder tree traversal algorithm. But I haven't found any analysis of the running time of this algorithm. Can someone give a runtime analysis of this algorithm? This link explains how Morris algorithm work. Thanks~~
[Explain Morris inorder tree traversal without using stacks or recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502916/explain-morris-inorder-tree-traversal-without-using-stacks-or-recursion)

Answer (score 4):

That's probably because it's so simple to deduce. There is a constant amount of work at every visit.  No node is visited more than three times (for a binary tree), so it's trivially O(n) where n is the number of nodes.