# binary tree traversal why need to check pre->right != current

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree

In a binary tree traversal algorithm like below cited from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502916/explain-morris-inorder-tree-traversal-without-using-stacks-or-recursion), why do we need to check the second condition 
`pre->right != current`? is this a loop condition? when would this happen?

```
  pre = current->left;
  while(pre->right != NULL && pre->right != current)
    pre = pre->right;
```

Comment: Is this an exercise? Where does the algorithm come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the latter code makes a cycle (i.e. child pointing to a parent):

```
pre->right = current;
```

The cycle is deleted later, however, but the `pre->right != current` test tris to avoid following the cycle endlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the tree given below,

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \  /\
D  E F  G
```

The node A which is the root is initialized as current. Now the code given by you tries to find out the immediate predecessor of A in inoreder traversal. As we know the inorder traversal of the given tree is as follows,

```
D  B  E  A  F  C  G
```

So the code identifies E as the immediate predecessor of A.

Answer (score 1):

[Pertaining to your [Question-code]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502916/explain-morris-inorder-tree-traversal-without-using-stacks-or-recursion)

Assume tree:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
```

It's In-order traversal = B,A,C

Now consider, B was already printed by

```
if(current->left == NULL)
    {
      printf(" %d ", current->data);
      current = current->right;
    }
```

So, **The Condition:**

```
pre->right != current
```

**is required to break while loop (which may be cyclic at times), exactly when our aim is to print node `A`.**

[image]

In this case, at the end of the while loop i.e. `while(pre->right != NULL && pre->right != current)`, we'll have :

1) `pre` pointing to left node `B` - which is already printed 
2) `current` pointing to middle node `A` - Next to be print, thus breaking cycle link we've created just for this. Following part takes care of this:

```
else
      {
        pre->right = NULL;           // Break cyclic link we've created for printing 'A'
        printf(" %d ",current->data);// prints 'A'
        current = current->right;    // Now, Aim for 'C'
      }
```