# Morris inorder Traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, graph-traversal

learning morris inorder traversal from here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/ and [Explain Morris inorder tree traversal without using stacks or recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502916/explain-morris-inorder-tree-traversal-without-using-stacks-or-recursion)

I am confused. 3 questions are in the comments. Help will be welcomed. Thanks

```
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.left == null) {
            visit(current);
            current = current.right;
        } else {
            pre = current.left;
            while (pre.right != null && pre.right != current) {
                pre = pre.right;
            } // Q1: why "pre.right != current"?
              // pre is initialized as current.left and will go right until null, 
              // why compare pre.right with current?

            if (pre.right == null) {
                pre.right = current;
                current = current.left;
            } else { // Q2: In which case, pre.right is not null and program gets here?
                pre.right = null;// Q3: why set pre.right to null?
                visit(current);
                current = current.right;
            }   

        } 

    }
```

Comment: Where are the questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if I understand correctly, this traversal essentially restructures the tree so that the left most node is at the root of the tree. So something that starts off like this:

```
     D
   /   \
  B     F
 / \   / \
A   C E   G
```

Will look like this:

```
A
 \
  B
 / \
A'  C
     \
      D
     / \
    B'  F
       / \
      E   G
```

Where `A'` is `A` and all its subtrees.

After visiting, it will reconstruct the tree back.

To answer your questions:

**Q1**

Before the reconstruction, `pre.right != current` will never be a loop-ending condition, i.e. it will never be true. However, after the reconstruction, imagine if `current` held `B`. `pre` would be set to `A'`, which is the same as `A`. `pre.right == A'.right == A.right == current`. Since this means that the `A'` node was already visited, it breaks the loop and reconstructs it, which leads to your next question.

**Q2**

Again, this case never happens prior to the reconstruction of the tree, but after the reconstruction, this is the "what to do" when you reach a node that's already been visited. Which again leads to your next question.

**Q3**

`pre.right` is set to `null` because it means prior to the reconstruction, the `pre.right` was originally null. Looking at the case post-reconstruction, node `B`, `pre` is set to `A`, which was a leaf node, and had no right child. Thus fixing it back:

```
  B
 / \
A   C
     \
      D
     / \
    B'  F
       / \
      E   G
```

As you can see, `A'` turned into just `A` since it's right child is no longer `B` but `null`.

Essentially, to help you understand it a bit better:

- Morris traversal reconstructs the tree to have it's root as it's left most node(Also note that it now has cyclic paths)
- Once it's been reconstructed, it will then visit, then fix the reconstruction back to the original form.