# Range function for values in a splay tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, pseudocode, splay-tree

I am a beginner at data structures.
I am trying to write some pseudocode for a range function with splay trees: `Range(S, A, B)`, which changes S to the set of all its members for which the key value C satisfies A ≤ C ≤ B. I know a splay trees fall into being types of binary search trees and implement their own splay operation. Basically, I am trying to return a range of values that are between A and B. However, I am having trouble understanding how I should do this, or where I should even begin, and what conditions I should check. I've read the definition of splay trees, and know they are like binary search trees with the move-to-front algorithm.

This is what I have so far:

```
Algorithm Range(Array S, int A, int B): array Set
S = new array(size) //Initialize an empty array of some size
if (A > B) then return NULL
```

I just feel somewhat lost after this point. I am not sure how to check the values of splay trees. Please let me know if I can provide additional information, or what directions I should go in.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree),

> A splay tree is a self-adjusting binary search tree with the additional property that recently accessed elements are quick to access again. It performs basic operations such as insertion, look-up and removal in O(log n) amortized time.

However, since the "splay" operation applies only to random searches, the tree may be considered to be an ordinary "binary search tree".

The algorithm becomes,

```
Range (BSTree T, int A, int B)
  int Array S

  S ← Empty array
  If A <= B then
    For each C in T
      If A <= C and C <= B then
        Append C to S
  Return S
```

That is, tree T is traversed, in order; and, for each item C meeting the condition, the item is added to array S. If no item meets the condition, an empty array is returned.

The `For each`, if not available in the implementation language, may be implemented using the algorithm described as [in-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order)

```
inorder(node)
  if (node = null)
    return
  inorder(node.left)
  visit(node)
  inorder(node.right)
```

where `vist(node)` is the place to test whether the item meets the condition.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use recursive algorithms on splay trees. They can be wildly out of balance, so the recursion stack can be as high as the tree has nodes.

Comment: @MattArmstrong What should be the approach then ?

Comment: @Riomare - *See*, [Explain Morris inorder tree traversal without using stacks or recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5502916/9170346).

Comment: @RickSmith I meant, what should be the approach to achieving amortized time  O(log n) without using recursion. I dont think Splaying only bounds will make it O(log n). If you are given splay tree in "shape" of linked list splaying only bounds will not make amortized O(log n) as it will only divide the height of tree only max in half no ? (This is also regarding second answer that is posted here)

Comment: @Riomare - O(log n) applies *only* to search times; that is, a splay tree search is O(log n) *on average*. Whether one is copying a range of items into an array, or removing items not in the range, requires an *in-order traversal* which is *not* O(log n). Where [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58734083/9170346) mentions dropping the left and right subtrees, it fails to mention deleting the items to free up resources which is where the *in-order traversal* is required.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late, but from the term "change" in the question prompt, it seems like it is asking you to modify the S tree so that it has only the elements within range.

So I would do it like this: splay the tree around the lower bound, and drop the left subtree, since everything in the left subtree will be lower value than the lower bound. Then splay the tree around upper bound, then dropping the right subtree, since everything in the right subtree will be higher value than the upper bound.

Here is how I would write it, in pseudocode

```
//assumes S is the root of an actual tree with elements
function Range(node S, int A, int B)
    node temp <- Splay(k1, S) //splay around lower bound
    if (temp.key < k1) //makes sure that there are elements in tree that satisfies this
        temp <- temp.right
        if (temp == null) return //there are no key greater than A, abort!
        temp <- Splay(temp.key, S)

    temp.left <- null //drops left subtree, bc they are all going to be lesser value
    temp <- Splay(k2, temp) //splay around upper bound
    if (temp.key > k2)
        temp <- temp.left
        if (temp == null) return //there are no keys less than B, abort!
        temp <- Splay(temp.key, temp)

    temp.right <- null //drops all right subtree
    S <- temp
```

Hope this helps! This should run in O(logn) also

Comment: Could you tell me which node you splay if you are only given a range? When you write Splay(k1,S), you splay root node ? also what is k1?

Comment: @sericsheon, find the lower bound of A.  A weakness of the answer above is that the same function `Splay` is used for two algorithms: lower and upper bound. The lower bound of A is the first node in the tree whose key is not less than A. To find the lower bound start at the root X and, first set a variable L null.  L will be your lower bound.  Then loop while X is not null.  In the loop compare X->key to A.  If X->key < a then simply set X to X->right and loop.  Otherwise set L to X and then X to X->left and loop.  When X is null return L as your lower bound.  Upper bound is similar.