# How can Morris inorder tree traversal have a space complexity of O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, space-complexity, inorder

I was reading about Morris inorder Traversal ([geekforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/), [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502916/explain-morris-inorder-tree-traversal-without-using-stacks-or-recursion)).

It seems that the advantage of Morris Traversal as opposed to recursion or iteration with a stack, is that the space complexity is `O(1)` instead of `O(h)` with `h` the height of the tree.

But when I am looking at the algorithm, it looks like you could have added up to `h` new pointers. Consider this spindly tree as a simple example:

```
      1
     /
    2
   / 
  3
 /
4
```

By the time you reach node 4, every node except the root would have a new pointer to its parent as a right child, which is `O(h)` new pointers.

Is the reason that in most programming languages, the `null` pointer takes the same space as a non-null pointer so changing the `right` pointer doesn't take any new space?

If it's the reason, I find it strange to have a language-agnostic algorithm relying on implementation details for its complexity. Looks like a convenient trick more than anything.

For example the space complexity would be wrong in JavaScript where changing `{left : node2}` to `{left: node2, right: node1}` would be taking more space.

Comment: You can have modified up to `h` pointers. But you did that in space you were already using, so no extra space required. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58191797/585411 for more.

Comment: @btilly but this is more of an implementation detail trick, isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely it is an implementation detail trick. From the era of 128k memory computers, and doubly linked lists that used an `xor` of pointers to save a pointer per node. Still theoretically interesting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article ["Traversing Binary Tree Siply and Cheaply", Joseph M. Morris, 16 December 1979](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0020019079900681), the author described the traversal that got to bear his name. The introduction states:

> The present algorithm uses no auxiliary storage other than two pointers.

It continues with the following assumptions:

> Each node in a tree has a unique name (in machine terms, an address), the empty node having the name **nil**. A ‘pointer’ is a variable of type ‘node name’.
>
> Each node t has two fields of interest, the left and right pointer fields, which are denoted by t.l and t.r, respectively. A pointer field (or ‘link’) whose value is
> not **nil** corresponds to an ‘edge’ of the tree.

Here we can see that the author defines a node as always having a field for the left child pointer and one for the right child pointer. It is only with that assumption that we can say no *other* auxiliary memory is needed.

If we define binary trees in a different way, for instance by using a **dynamically sized** node structure (e.g. with a dynamic *array* for the node's children), then this assumption is no longer true, and so we cannot take the *implication* for granted either.